# Can't pull information from MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py

Every attempt to pull information from DB about user returns `None`.

My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def warnings(ctx, user:discord.Member = None):
    client = MongoClient('connection')
    db = client.gettingStarted
    collection = db.Warning
    if user == None:
        await ctx.send('Please give a valid user')
    else:
        x = collection.find_one({"id":f"{user.id}"})
        print(x)
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
 x = collection.find_one({"id":f"{user.id}"})
```

to

```
 x = collection.find_one({"id": user.id})
```

Let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: What is the intuition behind this suggestion?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas when using f string, you change the value to a string, so he is looking for "id" using string, when the value in the mongodb is integer. So basically x will return None, because the db cant find "id" with the  value string: user.id.